# CocosDenshion music fade out

Tags: objective-c, ios, audio, cocos2d-iphone

I'm using cocos denshion for the music in my game.
I'm currently playing background music with the code: 
**[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic:@"backSong.mp3"];**

However, when the game ends, I need the background music to fade out gradually. How can I fade out the background music, is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance!
Additionally, is ObjectAL any better than CocosDenshion? If so, what are the differences/advantages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way i found of doing that is to schedule a method for execution and change the volume setting accordingly, kind of as follows:

```
-(void) fadeOutBackgroundMusic{
    if (!currentBackgroundMusic_) {
        CCLOG(@"GESoundServicesProviderImpl<fadeOutBackgroundMusic> : No background music at this time, ignoring.");
        return;
    }

    fadeOutActionTickerCount_=0;
    [self schedule:@selector(tickMusicFadeOut:)];

}

-(BOOL) isPlayingBackgroundMusic{
    return isPlayingBackgroundMusic_;
}

#pragma mark sequencing stuff

-(void) tickMusicFadeOut:(ccTime) dt{

    static float fadeTime;
    static float volume;
    static float maxVolume;

    fadeOutActionTickerCount_++;
    if (1==fadeOutActionTickerCount_) {
        isPerformingFadeOutAction_ =YES;
        fadeTime=0.0f;
        volume=0.0f;
        maxVolume=audioSettings_.masterVolumeGain*audioSettings_.musicCeilingGain;

    } else {

        fadeTime+=dt;
        volume=MAX(0.0f, maxVolume*(1.0 - fadeTime/K_MUSIC_FADE_TIME));
        [self setMusicVolume:volume];

        if (fadeTime>K_MUSIC_FADE_TIME) {
            volume=0.0f;                        // in case we have a .000000231 type seting at that moment.
        }


        if (volume==0.0f) {
            CCLOG(@"GESoundServicesProviderImpl<tickMusicFadeOut> : background music faded out in %f seconds.",fadeTime);
            [self setMusicVolume:0.0f];
            [sharedAudioEngine_ stopBackgroundMusic];
            self.currentBackgroundMusic=nil;
            isPlayingBackgroundMusic_=NO;
            isPerformingFadeOutAction_=NO;
            [self unschedule:@selector(tickMusicFadeOut:)];
        }
    }

}
```

this is a simplified (edited) sample from my sound services provider implementation class (not tested as shown here). The general idea is to schedule yourself a method that will gradually fade out the music over a period of time (here an app-wide constant, K_MUSIC_FADE_TIME).

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
float currentVolume = [SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine].backgroundMusicVolume;
id fadeOut = [CCActionTween actionWithDuration:1 key:@"backgroundMusicVolume" from:currentVolume to:0.0f];
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] actionManager] addAction:fadeOut target:[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] paused:NO];
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: clever implementation in only 3 lines.  I love smart code.  This answer should be preferred based on the question.