# SimpleAudioEngine background volume with CCActionTween

Tags: iphone, ios4, cocos2d-iphone, simpleaudioengine

Is it possible to have a fade out effect for SimpleAudioEngine background music using the CCActionTween? I know that the volume property is an float  between 1 and 0.

If it is possible, then a sample code would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there are no mechanisms within cocos2d to do what you are asking about. A CCNode derivative has the runAction method, but there are no CCNode derivatives for that embed sound controls. I perform sound fade in-out in the main loop as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10691897/cocosdenshion-music-fade-out/10709369#10709369) . The method ***fadeOutBackgroundMusic*** is exposed by a singleton, and available anywhere in the code. It has a corresponding fadeInBackgroundMusic method.